# Access Denied even on Signed Jar

Tags: java, jsp, io, applet, filenotfoundexception

I am using Applet and jar signer to sign the jar file ,but still getting error ,my java version is 51

```
        hiiiii
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\dest (Access is denied)
     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at UploadApplet.actionPerformed(UploadApplet.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My manifest file contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: Applet
permissions: all-permissions
Trusted-Only: true
Trusted-Library: true
```

Comment: Do you have certifica from CA or you've created it? If your applet is self-signed, Java will block applet anyway.

Comment: hi please tell how to create it and use it,i have used keytool -genkey to generate store and signed jar using it

Comment: I mean CA - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority, you will have to pay for it.

Comment: But for tests you can in java 7u51 add your site (e.g. localhost) to exception list - http://www.java.com/en/download/exception_sitelist.jsp but it will work only on your computer.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) Note that `FileNotFoundException` is **not the same as** an `AccessControlException`.. 3) My best guess is the code is attempting to write to a non-existent file, or a directory.  But I don't like guessing, so post a MCTaRE.

Comment: problem solved when i dont use localhost server,means when i put jar file on another server strange :D